# How i add custom search for mobile

Tags: openlayers

I want to make a custom search for my mobile website. That will show marker on my family members house by searching there name.

I have a list of latitude and longitude with family members name.

I am trying by open layer map and I tried by some tutorials but they didn't show me how to make custom search. Suggest me a way to make this.

http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch11-creating-web-map-apps/example-11.html
By this tutorial the search bar shows but it doesn't shows the map in my mobile.

Comment: The link refers to Openlayers 3. Current version is 5.3.0. Take a look at his website under the title "search": https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/

Comment: @RalphL  I don't think OpenLayers version is the problem here.  If you replace the `ol.js` link with the latest OpernLayers 6.0.0 beta `https://openlayers.org/en/master/build/ol.js` that code will still work with a desktop browser (but many of the ol-ext controls which use map canvas won't work with OL6).  It's more likely a page layout problem, for example when using OpenLayers on a mobile device it is important to include `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">` in the html header.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a search control in a responsive way you have to use a target options to place it in a responsive div:

```
map.addControl( new SearchControl({
  ...
  target: elementDiv
}
```

Then use the CSS media query to place it at the right place depending on the device size.

Here is an example: https://2x1pq0pz9n.codesandbox.io/

Press the search button and resize the window to see how it react:

- portrait: search is on the bottom part of the screen
- landscape: search is on the left part of the screen
- small (smartphone): search use the full screen

The code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/2x1pq0pz9n

As Mike says you also have to add a meta viewport in the header.